# Store each collection or record in separate folders in zip file using MediaStream

Tags: php, laravel, media-library

I have 4 media collections per user.

How can I create folders for each media collections and add media for each collection inside the folder in MediaStream?

Inside zip, it should look like Folder 1 with all media from collection 1, Folder 2 with media from collection 2, etc.

Code below adds all media in zip.

```
$downloads = Media::where('model_id',$user->id)->get();
return MediaStream::create($user->code.'.zip')->addMedia($downloads);
```

I saw the documentation but I can't figure out how I can use this to get what I need.

```
$mediaItem = Media::find($id);

$mediaItem->setCustomProperty('zip_filename_prefix', 'folder/subfolder/'); // stores $mediaItem in Subfolder

$mediaItem->save();

$mediaStream =  MediaStream::create('export.zip');
$mediaStream->addMedia($mediaItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer.
In my case, I needed to obtain the collections
whose relation has media associated with it.
The "jobs" table is the parent table of "jobMediaNotes".

So I have a list of "jobs" and each job may (or may not) another relationship called "jobMediaNotes". Each "jobMediaNote" may (or may not) have a collection of media uploaded for the note.

Here is how I achieved my result. Since mine is like a 2-layered problem, you may have to remove one of the foreach loops to satisfy your condition.

```
// $zip_file_name can be any name you want to give to the zip file for your clients to download (stream to their browser).

$mediaStream = MediaStream::create($zip_file_name);

// as mentioned, each "job" has (or may not have) another model "jobMediaNote" related to it. 
// So I go through each job and obtain the "jobMediaNotes" for that particular "job".

// I have defined the name of the collection. 
// Yours could be the default collection name.

$mediaCollectionName = "jobs";

foreach($jobs as $key => $value) {
    $job = $value;
    $jobMediaNotes = $value->jobMediaNotes;

    $job_id = $job->id;
        
    // The parent folder is the folder in the zip for each "job" (or collection). 


    // In this example, one of the folders can be called "Job #138".

    $parent_folder = "Job #" . $job_id . "/";

    // The path is not necessary but I want to keep the entire zip in a 
    // root folder which I call "Jobs" in this case.
    // The path will now be dynamic. I am naming the path based on the collection's id. 

    $path = "Jobs/" . $parent_folder;

    foreach($jobMediaNotes as $mediaNote) {
    // This will add the media in it's respective folders 
    // to keep the zip archive a little organized

    // I need to get the media files for a particular note. 
    // Which means I need to iterate over the collection.

     $mediaCollection = $mediaNote->getMedia($mediaCollectionName);

    foreach ($mediaCollection as $media) {
       // This is what the documentation was talking about so do as it says.

        $media->setCustomProperty('zip_filename_prefix', $path);
        $media->save();

        // Now, add the media to the path.
        $mediaStream->addMedia($media);
        }
    }
}

// Finally, output the media for streaming (downloading)

return $mediaStream;
```

That's all. Done.

Reference link: [Here is a link to the documentation if anyone needs it again :)](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v8/advanced-usage/using-custom-properties#content-zip-file-folders)